# Where are Android contacts stored?

Tags: contacts

I have a dual-boot Linux/Android phone. I want to get my contacts off the Android partition. Where is that file stored?
I tried googling it, but it seems like everyone is trying to sell me an app that does it.

I'd rather store it in a location and use it/add to it from Linux, but I need the path/file name.

(I had to wipe my OS last night after some kernel hacking left me high and dry, so it'll be a minute before I can get back to a good working version of Linux. :( I should have made a backup, but I didn't)

Comment: Your contacts must be synced to Google if you had sync turned on.

Comment: Interesting question.  Which dual boot Linux / Android phone are you using?  Do you recommend it?

Comment: The cosmo communicator. its pretty ok. its a weird setup in actuality. the thing has better specs that might make it good for playing games on andriod, but the layout kinda makes it hard to do that. the linux "support" is kinda meh too. I got it thinking I could use cellphone sensors to integrate into linux games, but its not documented very well, all the devices in the device tree are fed via andriod, interfacing from linux is harder than it needs to be. it also breaks loads of existing libraries. the OEM is pretty restrictive. I was trying to build out debian devtools when I broke it.

Comment: I mean, its not broken, just all the work I did to the OS is gone